# How to insert same data in 1 table and Limit it by 10

Tags: mysql

I am working in a "Recently view by user" script. I have 3 tables, `tbl_user, tbl_articles and tbl_recently_viewed.` My tbl_recently_viewed has 3 fields, `user_id(from tbl_user),article_id(from tbl_articles) and date,` and i made 2 primary keys, `user_id and article_id.` My problem is i want to limit a certain user_id to be inserted in tbl_recently_viewed by 10. Is there a way i can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add a new row to `tbl_recently_viewed` and delete the old rows if there are more than 10?

Comment: exactly. is there a way i can do it?

Comment: Isn't it easier to remove the limit on how many rows are allowed, and just fetch the 10 latest ones through your query?

Comment: @SimonCarlson That's not trivial using myquery, either. It doesn't have a `TOP N` operator.

Comment: Before inserting, check whether `COUNT(*)` is 10, and delete the oldest one.

Comment: @Simon Carlson If i do that my table will have thousands of data in it since i will adding data in tbl_recently_viewed by just clicking the article. If 1 user clicks around 20 articles per day, and atleast i will have 100 users, every day it will consume 2000 data.

Comment: @Joem Maranan makes sense, I didn't catch exactly how it'd work. Do what Barmar said and check the amount of rows before inserting.

Comment: @Barmar that is what i'm thinking but how can i compare those 10 and only erase the oldest one. I need help here.

Comment: To delete the oldest row for user use `delete from tbl_recently_viewed where user_id=1 order by date limit 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the oldest item for a user from `tbl_recently_viewed`:

```
DELETE v.* FROM tbl_recently_viewed v
JOIN (SELECT MIN(date) mindate
      FROM tbl_recently_viewed
      WHERE user_id = ?) r
ON v.date = r.mindate
WHERE user_id = ?
```

Comment: To delete oldest one better to use `delete from tbl_recently_viewed where user_id=1 order by date limit 1;`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a trigger to do what you want to do.  If you are only inserting rows, then you can use an insert trigger to remove the oldest.

The following is intended just as an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_keep10 after INSERT ON t
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     if (10 > (select count(*) from t where t.user_id = new.user_id)) then
         delete from t where t.article_id = (select a from (select article_id as a from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id order by date desc limit 1))
     end if;
  END;
|
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it also works but the answer of Barmar is more simplified so i am choosing his answer as my accepted. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete rows after 10 with this query:

```
delete from tbl_recently_viewed where user_id=1 and date <= (select max(date) from (select date from tbl_recently_viewed where user_id=1 order by date desc limit 10,999) as tmp);
```

or just delete oldest row with query:

```
delete from tbl_recently_viewed where user_id=1 order by date limit 1;
```